# AWS - Elastic Beanstalk - Stack named 'awseb-e-seqmhv7s3e-stack' aborted operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I need to deploy my Appliactio using Load balanced (Not in a single instance).

But I got these two errors.

**"Stack named 'awseb-e-seqmhv7s3e-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition]."**

After this error events show this error.

**"LaunchWaitCondition failed. The expected number of EC2 instances were not initialized within the given time. Rebuild the environment. If this persists, contact support."**

Can you help me to fix this error, please?

[image]

Comment: I am now experiencing the same error. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably placed your instances in a private subnet, thus the EB can't initialize them. You have to setup a NAT gateway in public subnets, with correctly configured route tables. This way the instances will be able to initialize.

Comment: could you able to provide a step-by-step guideline for this? Any online resources, please...